# how can i communicate with webview, i want to search character using textWatcher

Tags: android-webview, searchview

i want to highLight sometext which is searched. (from editText)

example : when i enter character ; 'yahoo' will be highLighted.
is this hard thing? im literally noob. but i wnat to do this.

i found method 'textWatcher'. he can just bring me character(when it's changed each time)

or do i use searchView?

please check my code. MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(watch); // == (this), implements TextWatcher

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.yahoo.com/");
    }

    TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
            Log.d("onTextChanged","CharSequence s #"+s);
        }

    };

}
```

also, i input permission-code in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

how do i fix this? please give me your tips.